# Create migration from sequelize models?

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I used sync({force:true}) while prototyping. I'm done and now want to launch.

I want to create a base migration file based on current model/db schema and translate into one migration file.

I know it can be done, I just don't know steps or vocabulary to search for it.